# small 1px gap in IE between two divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In the code below, all is displayed correctly in Chrome and Firefox. The `inner` element fully stretched to the `outer`.

In IE11, the `inner` element is not fully stretched to the container. And there is exist 1px gaps like on a picture.[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    .outer {
      background-color: yellow;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .inner {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div>Outer</div>
    <div class="inner">Inner</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

1. Why does it happen?
2. How to fix it?

**UPD1.** To reproduce it, you should zoom the page.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I have no idea why this happens, but at least I've found a way to fix it.

I thought I could use `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;` and remove the border, but this scales the element differently (and IE's really bad at rendering thin box-shadows, would produce more unexpected results than this). Setting the outer div to `overflow: hidden;` and using a green box-shadow on the inner one to fill the gap didn't work too, box-shadow got cut off. Even flexbox and floating stuff didn't help, and it seems not like a box-sizing or line-height issue.

The only thing that worked is replacing the border with `outline: 1px solid black;`

This scales the element different too, but it can be readjusted by adding a 1px padding + the box-shadow approach to fill the gap:

```
.outer {
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: yellow;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    outline-offset: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    background-color: green;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 green;
}
```